# inconsistent need for global keyword when referencing variables in other PHP scripts

Tags: php, global, require

I've hunted for an answer to this, but still can't explain the inconsistency i'm experiencing. Heregoes...

I'm writing a simple CMS in PHP and cannot understand how I can directly reference external variables from one `require` call but not another
1. Here's my Db_Conn.php script.

```
<?php
if(!class_exists('Db_Conn')){
    class Db_Conn{
        var $pdo;
        public function __construct(){
                $init_array = parse_ini_file('conf.ini');
            try{
                $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $init_array['host'] . ';dbname=' . $init_array['database'], $init_array['user'], $init_array['password']);
            } catch(PDOException $ex){
                exit('Database Error!');
            }

        }
    }
    $db_conn = new Db_Conn();
}   
?>
```

2. Here's my simplified article_manager script, that requires the previous DB connection script.

```
<?php
require_once('class-db_conn.php');

if(!class_exists('Article_Manager')){
    class Article_Manager{
        public function fetch_article($article_id){
        global $db_conn;
        $query = $db_conn->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetch();
    }


    }
    $article_manager = new Article_Manager();
}
?>
```

In this script I can only reference the $db_conn variable is via the global keyword. This makes sense and there are plenty of threads about avoiding globals.

But here's my confusion. Here's a third script that requires the article_manager.

```
<?php
require_once('includes/class-article_manager.php');

if (!isset($_GET['id'])){
    //no page set, back to index
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
} else {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $selected_article = $article_manager->fetch_article($id);
    //...some code left out
?>
```

When I `require` the article_manager script I DONT have to use global. I can simply call the functions of the $article_manager variable without global referencing.

Could someone please tell me what is going on here? Why don't I have to use `global` in the second example. I realise the use of globals is discouraged, so I was hoping I could use an alternative method to keep my code encapsulated and.

Comment: Maybe this will do the trick : $GLOBALS += get_defined_vars(); where you can append all defined variables to $GLOBALS and access them wherever you want.You just need to call this on whatever script you need those variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Article_Manager` needs to use `global` because it's calling `$db_conn` within the `fetch_article` function which has it's own scope.

In your second example you're just calling `$article_manager` within an if statement, presumably already in the global / main scope.

The general idea is that when you want to access variables from within a function they either need to be passed in as an argument or, in this case, a global variable.

Comment: Thanks, Chad, as a noob I knew there was a chance of asking a silly question. I'd been staring at the code and couldn't work it out.